# Should i upgrade to Angular 8 to migrate Web App to NativeScript?

Tags: angular, angular5, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

The Web App is built in Angular 5. I have not found any tutorials or docs that clearly define this. NativeScript has some really good tutorials on how to migrate from Angular 8 to NativeScript, but i am not quite sure about Angular 5.

To come to my question, is the best approach to update to Angular 8 and then migrate to NativeScript or is there any tutorial i can use to migrate directly from Angular 5.

Comment: Yes, you will have to upgrade. The angular code sharing is based on schematics which is not available for Angular 5.

Answer (score 1):

The most safe way is to upgrade to Angular 8 first and than migrate your code into NS, but I would try the direct way if you dont have enough time, but this might end up in trouble.